# Form to submit variables from two inputs

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to $_POST two variables when this form is submitted, it auto submits when an image is selected, that's fine. But it only posts the image value, not the hidden value, I need both  variables to be sent so the variables from both inputs need to submit. Individually they work fine, if I change the hidden input to an image it happily posts the value, but again, only of itself not of both inputs. Any ideas?

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <?php
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, project FROM models.models where models.active = 'yes'");


    $query->execute();
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "
<input type='image' style='height:100px; padding:5px; margin :20px;' id='1' class='img-fluid img-thumbnail' src='models/thumbs/",$r->name,".jpg' name='name' value='",$r->name,"'/>
<input type='hidden' id='1' name='group' value='",$r->project,"'/>
    ";
    }
?>

</form>
```

Comment: How many records are supposed to be returned from your SQL query ? If >1 your form will break because all the fields created in the while() loop have the same "name" attribute value, you have to make it change somehow at each iteration.

Comment: about 10 records, it outputs fine, each image has its correct value and when clicked sends the value to the session.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Oh I see! Of course! so how do I overcome this issue? Through an array?

Comment: I'm not sure inputs with type image work as you expect here, which might explain the problem you are facing. You want the form to submit the name and project for the user's selection right ? If so, I'd suggest you split up things so that each record has its own form, and a regular submit button (You may display the image with a regular image type or whatever). You can still pass the name value through another hidden input.

Comment: Yes, the user selects an image the project the image name and project is passed to the session variables as the current selected image/project. Ok, so say we change the input to a button, it has the value $r->name and there is a hidden input with the value $r->project and a standard submit input. Then it should work?

Comment: If you just change the input to a button, you should have 20 fields submitted at once along the form (which is not what you want) but most of them have the same name, so the fields actually submitted might not be the ones you want. Better split the whole thing into individual forms as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A candidate solution based on our comments, changing the input image to a button, displaying the image in a separate tag and splitting the list into multiple forms :

```
<?php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, project FROM models.models where models.active = 'yes'");

$query->execute();
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

    <img style='height:100px; padding:5px; margin :20px;' src="models/thumbs/<?php echo $r->name; ?>.jpg" />
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="<?php echo $r->name; ?>" />
    <input type='hidden' id='1' name='group' value='",$r->project,"'/>
    </form>
<?php 
}
?>
```